# How to solve a glassfish error when trying to use apache Spark with Springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-spark, etl

I am trying to read a CSV file from a database using apache spark and then print each line in the console (just to test). The csv file in encoded to utf8 when I upload it to the database then decoded when I try print it. I am getting the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/glassfish/jersey/server/spi/Container
    at org.apache.spark.status.api.v1.ApiRootResource$.getServletHandler(ApiRootResource.scala:63) ~[spark-core_2.12-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
    at org.apache.spark.ui.SparkUI.initialize(SparkUI.scala:70) ~[spark-core_2.12-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
    at org.apache.spark.ui.SparkUI.<init>(SparkUI.scala:80) ~[spark-core_2.12-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
    at org.apache.spark.ui.SparkUI$.create(SparkUI.scala:178) ~[spark-core_2.12-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:444) ~[spark-core_2.12-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2526) ~[spark-core_2.12-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.$anonfun$getOrCreate$1(SparkSession.scala:930) ~[spark-sql_2.12-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189) ~[scala-library-2.12.10.jar:na]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:921) ~[spark-sql_2.12-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
    at com.example.dbtest.model.Job$1.run(Job.java:90) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.dbtest.components.JobScheduler.lambda$updateJobList$0(JobScheduler.java:49) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:96) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:577) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.Container
```

This is the code I am trying to execute:

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf()
    .setAppName("dbtest")
    .setMaster("local[*]"); // Set the master URL for local testing

// Create a SparkSession using the SparkConf object
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
    .config(sparkConf)
    .getOrCreate();

String jdbcUrl = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydatabase";
String username = "postgres";

// Read the file data from the database table, selecting the "body" column
Dataset<Row> pdfData = spark.read()
    .format("jdbc")
    .option("url", jdbcUrl)
    .option("dbtable", "configurations")
    .option("user", username)
    .load()
    .select("body");

// Convert the fileData DataFrame to an RDD of Strings
Dataset<String> pdfContent = pdfData
    .withColumn("body", functions.col("body")
    .cast("string"))
    .select("body")
    .as(Encoders.STRING());
// Perform further processing or analysis on the fileLinesRDD
System.out.println(pdfContent);
```

And this is my pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>dbtest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>dbtest</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>

            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <!-- Add more exclusions if needed -->
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.8</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-reload4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hadoop-yarn-client</artifactId>
                </exclusion>



            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-yarn-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.8</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-reload4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.8</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-reload4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.32</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.26</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: `<exclusion><groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId><artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId></exclusion>` might have something to do with not loading the class `org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.Container`

Comment: @Bohemian I tried omitting that exclusion but I still get the same error.

Comment: Did you remove the `jersey-server` exclusion? The class `org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.Container` is in the `org.glassfish.jersey.core` jar: Perhaps you should add that as a dependency too.